# Do I need to delete a dynamically allocated object in Singly Linked List?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, c++17, singly-linked-list

I am currently learning Linked Lists and have implemented a singly linked list with Append and Prepend methods where I have allocated objects of type Node on heap using the 'new' operator. Do I need to deallocate the object on heap using 'delete', and if so then how do I do it ?
Here is my code:-

```
class List
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node()
        {
            data = 0;
            next = NULL;
        }
        Node(const int& data)
        {
            this->data = data;
        }
    };

    Node* head;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void Append(const int&val);
    void Prepend(const int&val);
    void DisplayAll();
};

void List::Append(const int&val)
{
    Node* n = new Node(val); //dynamically allocated 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    Node* temp = NULL;
    temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = n;
}

void List::Prepend(const int&val)
{
    Node* node = new Node(val);//dynamically allocated 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}

void List::DisplayAll()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << temp->data << ' ';
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Any* dynamically allocated data needs to be `delete`d if not needed any more, otherwise you have a memory leak. This includes your nodes as well.

Comment: You can write a destructor (e.g. `~Node() { ... }`) that does that for you. (which would be the proper way to ensure the class cleans up after itself) e.g. `~Node() { while (head) { Node *victim = head; head = head->next; delete victim; } }`

Comment: Also, if you add a `tail` pointer (e.g. `Node *head, *tail;`) and always have `tail` point to the last node in your list, you can `append` in O(1) time without iteration.

Comment: Side note: Get used to implement the constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `List() : head(nullptr) { }`. This prefers direct initialisation over default initalisation + assignment, additionally some member types (const ones, references, non-assignable ones) *only* can be initialised that way. Furthermore you should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: Side note 2: In `append` you have a needless double assignment left (`Node* temp = NULL; temp = head;`) – you might want to fix to the variant in `prepend`: `Node* temp = head;`.

Comment: While fine for *learning* please keep in mind that there's already [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) doing exactly the same, which you should use later on instead of the reinvented wheel. About learning: Next step would be converting your list into a template one to be able to add arbitrary data types.

Comment: Every C++ class should adhere to the rule of three/five/zero.

Answer (score 2):

For starters this constructor

```
    Node(const int& data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
```

does not initialize the data member `next`. As a result member functions `Append` and `Prepend` have a bug

```
void List::Append(const int&val)
{
    Node* n = new Node(val); //dynamically allocated 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    //...
```

and

```
void List::Prepend(const int&val)
{
    Node* node = new Node(val);//dynamically allocated 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    //...
```

The data member `next` of the head node has an indeterminate value.

You could declare the class `Node` simpler like

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head = nullptr;
```

In this case for example the function `Prepend` will look like

```
void List::Prepend( const int &val )
{
    head = new Node { val, head };
}
```

And the constructor will look like

```
List() = default;
```

To free all allocated nodes in the list you could write two more member functions `clear` and the destructor that calls the function `clear`.

For example

```
#include <functional>

//...

class List
{
//...
public:
    void clear()
    {
        while ( head ) delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
    }

    ~List() { clear(); }
    //...
```

Also you should at least either write a copy constructor and the copy assignment operator or define them as deleted.